# Invertibility of operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, differential-operators

Gives conditions under which $L$ is an invertible operator.

$L:u \rightarrow -u''+p(x)u'+q(x)u$

$u \in dom(L)= \{u\in C^{2}[a,b], u'(a)-\theta_{a}u(a)=0, u'(b)+\theta_{b}u(b)=0 \} $

$\theta_{a}, \theta_{b} \ge 0$

I thought to check if the operator is positive with these condition, but I don't know if it's a good way. I'm looking for some tips.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to compute the inner product (Lu,u) in L2

Comment: So idea about positivity was good, yes?

Comment: Yes, look at the definition of positive operator. It remains to compute the scalar product.

Comment: Yes yes, I know, thanks.

Comment: After calculations I received $$\theta_{b}u^{2}(b)+\theta_{a}u^{2}(a)+\int_{a}^{b}(u')^{2}dx+\frac{1}{2}(u^{2}(b)p(b)-u^{2}(a)p(a))-\frac{1}{2} \int_{a}^{b} u^{2}p'dx+\int_{a}^{b} u^{2}qdx$$ So $p(x)$ has to be decreasing and $u(b) \ge u(a)$ Is that good?